# If the set of solutions to these inequalities are the same, one can conclude that...

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

If $a>0$ and the inequalities $$a^{x^3}  >  \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{x+1} \tag{1}$$
$$x^3+x+1  <  0 \tag{2}$$

Have the same set of solutions, then one can conclude that

a) $a>1$

b) $a=1$

c) $a<1$

d) None of the above.

If we tamper with (1) we get the $$a^{x^3}>a^{-x-1}\Leftrightarrow a^{x^3}\cdot a^{-x-1}=a^{x^3+x+1}>0.$$

This implies that for what ever value of the polynomial, the LHS will always be positive since $a>0,$ this means that it holds for all $a>0$, but it's not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

In your tampering, you should end up with $$ a^{x^3+x+1}> 1$$ with $1$ not $0$ when you divide both sides by $a^{-x-1}$

Comment: But the answer is c). Not a).

Comment: Indeed (c) is correct since if the solutions for   $a^{x^3+x+1}> 1$ coincide with those for $x^3+x+1  <  0 $ (spot the change in direction of signs) then $a \lt 1$

Comment: So how can I go from $a^{x^3+x+1}>1$ to $x^3+x+1<0$? If I logarithm both sides i just get $x^3+x+1>0$

Comment: @Parseval The map $f: y\mapsto a^y$ is always $1$ in $0$, i.e. $f(0)=1$, but depending on whether the positive base $a$ is under or over one, the map can be decreasing or increasing. So if $y<0$, is $a^y$ greater than or less than $1$?

Comment: Taking natural logarithms  $a^{x^3+x+1}>1 \implies (x^3+x+1)\log_e a > 0$ so the two expressions  $x^3+x+1 $ and $\log_e a$ must have the same sign. For this to be consistent with $x^3+x+1 < 0 $ leads to $\log_e a < 0 \implies a < 1$

Comment: Ofcourse! Thanks a lot Henry!